# NFC and Bluetooth enabled ISO 14443 smartcard/tag for iPhone pairing

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, nfc, smartcard

Although iPhones have NFC hardware, the iOS APIs do not allow the access to this NFC hardware that is needed to read the contactless (RFID) chips embedded in ISO 14443 smartcards and tags. Newer iPhone models can read NFC in a very limited manner.

Is anyone aware if there is an ISO 14443 smartcard or tags with Bluetooth. The iPhone app would initiate via NFC, receive the Bluetooth address, pair Bluetooth with the card and phone, then resume all further communication between phone and card via Bluetooth.

Kind regards, Justin

Comment: iOS doesn't support Bluetooth pairing using NFC.  The only NFC functionality available t apps is reading NDEF tags via Core NFC

Answer (score 1):

The superficial similarity of wireless communication does not indicate the substantial differences on lower levels:

NFC tags have no power source of their own, instead they exploit the radio waves used for communication and are always the slave of the communication.

Bluetooth (even LE) is a powerful and complex (peer-level) protocol, which requires a dedicated power supply - there is no other way to achieve sending power of 10 to 100 mW. It is surely possible to wire something together understanding both protocols, but the plain vanilla tag can't achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you been tying [this reader](https://www.ftsafe.com/products/reader/bluetooth)?

This is standard smart-card reader. It is connected to iPhone via Bluetooth and support both - contact and contactless cards.

Theoretically You can create an NFC tag with pairing information, but you will need an application to activate NFC module of iPhone to read tag's NDEF payload.